# What kind of soup is this lady most likely making?

Tags: food-identification

I was watching Gordon's Great Escape: Vietnamese and they do a scene with an old lady selling soup. However, it isn't clear what kind of soup she actually makes only that it at the very least contains banana blossoms, bean sprouts, water spinach thins, vermicelli noodles, sweet basil and the broth seems to be an orange like color.

A link to the video is here: [Gordon's Great Escape: Vietnamese](https://youtu.be/iTIkSvz333k?t=20m7s) and for your benefit the link should led to start of the scene that I am talking about. If it doesn't the scene starts at 20:07 ish.

Hopefully, that is enough to work off of.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are actually two dishes being sold, and neither is "Phở". The words that she yelled and had Gordon do the same were "Hủ tiếu, Bún riêu". They are both noodle soups, the former is pork based broth, and the latter, porc and shrimp/crab with tomatoes. You can google the words for more info.